# Visual Studio 9.0 Error C2051 Case Expression Not Constant

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors

When I try to compile this code, I get a `Case Expression Not Constant` error. I can't figure out why.

```
while ((*datalen) == 0)
    crReturn(NULL);  //error here
st->len = (st->len << 8) + **data;
```

The function crReturn() is defined as following.

```
#define crReturn(z) \
do {\
    *crLine =__LINE__; return (z); case __LINE__:;\
} while (0)
```

Comment: Is this code within a `switch` statement? If not, perhaps MSVC++ (confusingly) gives a C2051 error when it sees a `case` that isn't inside a `switch`; I don't have a copy of MSVC++9 handy, but you could test this by sticking a random `case 0:` somewhere in your code and seeing what error you get from it. (What's the actual intended use of `crReturn`?)

Comment: Oh. You're using Simon Tatham's coroutine stuff, aren't you? In that case, I can't help thinking that you deserve all the pain you get :-). Did you perhaps fail to put a `crBegin;` at the start of your function and a `crEnd;` at the end?

Comment: I notice the following in Simon Tatham's page about his coroutine macros. "Note that Visual C++ version 6 doesn't like this coroutine trick, because its default debug state (Program Database for Edit and Continue) does something strange to the __LINE__ macro." I don't *expect* this problem is present in later versions of MSVC++, but you might try turning off Edit and Continue and see if that helps at all.

Comment: @Gareth it looks to me like the case statement is in the crReturn function.

Comment: The `case` is in the expansion of the `crReturn` macro, but I was asking about the `switch` that the `case` is a part of. (It's part of the expansion of the `crBegin` macro, as it turns out. When I asked the question I hadn't made the connection with Simon's coroutine code.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Also, this isn't my code. This is the source code from the svn repository for putty. I'm trying to build obj files from visual studio 9.0 and getting the error mentioned above. I'm trying to figure out why and get past it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Interesting. Then I bet there's nothing wrong with the placement of the `crBegin` and `crEnd`, unless you tweaked the code in some highly inadvisable way :-). I suggest you try turning off edit-and-continue next, and see whether that helps.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan After disabling edit and continue, I get the same exact list of errors.

Comment: Damn. It occurs to me that "disable edit-and-continue" may be ambiguous, so let me be clear about what I think needs doing: what matters is the "Debug Information Format" (on the "C/C++ -> General" property page), which needs to be set to something other than "Program Database for Edit and Continue". If doing this and rebuilding doesn't help, then I think I'm out of ideas; you might want to contact Simon Tatham...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan That solved that problem. Please post as answer so I can accept it. If you'd like to help me with my next problem with the project, I would greatly appreciate it. You're very helpful. :)

Comment: Answer posted. I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Almost missed that. Should've accepted it sooner. Thanks for watching out for me. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that MSVC++ does something nonstandard (and contrary to its own documentation) when it's configured to generate debug information for its "edit and continue" feature, and that this nonstandard breaks the way that `__LINE__` is used in Simon Tatham's coroutine macros.

Here's what the comments in the PuTTY source code say about this:

```
In particular, if you are getting `case expression not constant'
errors when building with MS Visual Studio, this is because MS's
Edit and Continue debugging feature causes their compiler to
violate ANSI C. To disable Edit and Continue debugging:

- right-click ssh.c in the FileView
- click Settings
- select the C/C++ tab and the General category
- under `Debug info:', select anything _other_ than `Program
Database for Edit and Continue'.
```

So you should probably do that. (In fact, I know that you already did, because we discussed this in comments before I posted this answer :-).)